# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't I have the option ''Install Ubuntu alongside with them''](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69481/why-dont-i-have-the-option-install-ubuntu-alongside-with-them)

I'm running Windows 7 on my HP laptop and I want to install Ubuntu on it. In the installation window I don't get the option for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows. I have only two options: remove windows and install ubuntu and something else...

Whats wrong?

Comment: Are You trying to use Wubi?

Comment: You might have a look at http://www.howtoforge.com/dualbooting-windows-7-and-linux-mint-12