# Problem with Ubuntu installation alongside WindowsXP

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-xp

I tried to install Ubuntu on my WindowsXP machine as a second OS.

I do not get the option "Install Ubuntu alongside them" when I go through the guided installation process from the Live-CD.

Any idea or help on what I could do?

Further information:

I have three primary partitions:

- (without title) 78MB FAT
- Recovery (D:) 10 GB NTFS
- (C:) 136.47 GB NTFS
- And one extended partition (as a logical drive): - Mediadirect 2.5 GB FAT 32

There is no unpartitioned disk space left

My drive is a basic drive and I ran chkdsk (no errors found) but the problem persists

Comment: I have three primary partitions:
- (without title) 78MB FAT
- Recovery (D:) 10 GB NTFS
- (C:) 136.47 GB NTFS
And one extended partition (as a logical drive):
- Mediadirect 2.5 GB FAT 32
There is no free space or unpartitioned disk space left

Comment: thanks - remember to edit your question with any replies to comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't I have the option ''Install Ubuntu alongside with them''](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69481/why-dont-i-have-the-option-install-ubuntu-alongside-with-them)

Comment: thanks for the hint! My drive is a basic drive and I ran chkdsk as described there (no errors found) but the problem persists

Comment: ... I think I have read somewhere that you must have a small amount of unallocated space available for the install alongside option to be visible... can you shrink your C: partition by 20-50GB first and rerun the install.  thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot fossfreedom. I am not very experienced with changing/shrinking partitions. Do you know any link where I could find an instruction on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you already have 4 partitions which is the maximum amount possible in the MBR partition table, so Ubuntu can't create another *primary* partition.

It would be able to create another *logical* partition inside your extended partition, but the latter is too small to install Ubuntu there.

So Ubuntu unstaller is literally out of options here :) You need to help it by shrinking your C: drive and then moving/resizing your extended partition to make it a bit larger. In the process you can even create an ext4 logical partition for your Ubuntu manually.

As I remember Ubuntu requires somewhere between 6 and 7 Gb of disk space to install.

Comment: That sounds very good, thanks a lot! I still have to find out how to shrink my C: drive as I am not very experienced with doing this kind of things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I managed to reduce the size of C: with gParted and have now successfully installed Ubuntu as a second OS!

Comment: Glad to hear! You can mark the answer as a solution then.