# How do I install Ubuntu on an HP laptop with four primary partitions?

Tags: windows, partitioning, dual-boot, hp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My HP laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-hp-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

I have a HP Pavilion g6 laptop. My drive already has 4 partitions on it, stock. I made a new 70 Gig partition and try to make a new simple volume and it says it has to make it a dynamic disk.

I am trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

The 4 stock partitions are:

- System
- (C:)
- Recovery (D:)
- HP_TOOLS(E:).