# Max 4 primary partitions.

Tags: disk

I have a bit a problem, I shrinked my windows partition. But it seems I have another partition for recovery and for my documents. I don't want to delete any of them. Is there any way to move one of them, like the document partition together with the new ubuntu partition in just one extended partition?

Comment: What is the exact problem? As I see it, you have 3 partitions (and a fourth one for ubuntu), so there's no trouble?

Comment: GParted gives the error that there can't be more then 4. So maybe it sees the space allocated or my USB stick (were ubuntu is running from atm) as primary partition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you become more specific in your post.  For example, edit it by saying partition #1 has X and partition #2 has Y, etc.

You can have only 4 primary partitions.  I had this problem recently, too.  You will need to make the 4th an extended partition and then put the other partitions in that.  Like you, the primary partitions was taken up by Windows and a recovery partition.

I use the gparted program to edit / move partitions under Ubuntu.  If it happens to be the root partition, then I boot off Ubuntu from a CD (or USB stick) and run gparted that way.  gparted can merge partitions or extend it.  It is graphical based so I think it is self-explanatory.  Of course, back up before you try...especially if you're planning to merge a Document partition...things can go wrong with any of the partitions, but the one you are extending / cutting, in particular.

Comment: Okay, I will try to run GParted from USB.