# Which installation drive to choose?

Tags: installation, windows

I'm using the Ubuntu installer

**Should I pick** *(C:) [39GB free]* or *(D:) [89GB free]*?

I keep all (0.5GB) of **files** on **(D:)** and keep installed **programs** on **(C:)**.

Will anything happen to my files if I choose (D:) or is there any chance of my files being lost?

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to use WUBI.EXE?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows then **yes**, if you choose to install Ubuntu on (D:) all you data will be erased.  This is because Ubuntu uses a totally different formatting system ([ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)) than Windows uses ([NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)).  Ubuntu won't run on `NTFS` and Windows won't run on `ext4`.

At this point you have two options:

**1**. You can create a new partition for Ubuntu (shrinking one of your others) and install Ubuntu there.  *NOTE:*   if your using a newer computer, you might already have four (4) primary partitions, the maximum  a hard drive can support. (There are [ways around](https://askubuntu.com/q/149821/44179) this, but I don't recommend them for new users)

**2**. Or you can use the [Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) ([WUBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(Ubuntu_installer))) to safely install Ubuntu inside of Windows in a kind of virtual partition.  If you install Ubuntu this way you can uninstall it like any other Windows program, which is great for beginners.

I recommend using WUBI if this is your first time using Ubuntu and aren't sure you want to commit.  Using WUBI eliminates accidental mistakes while partitioning, making it a safer route for beginners.