# Partitioning issues with easeUS how do i proceed

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Ok I installed EaseUS to set up a partition for Ubuntu. My laptop automatically has 4 primary drives:

```
*:SYSTEM
C:
D: Recovery
*: HP_TOOLS
```

I have an HP laptop. I read online that HP_TOOLS is a back up of the BIOS and that I can convert it to a logic drive, no problem. I was able to convert it, and I was able to take 15 GB from the C: drive to unpartitioned space. Now it won't let me partition that space to a separate drive for Ubuntu. It says I need to convert another drive to a logic drive. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, you don't have to create a partition out of that unallocated (free) space to be able to install Ubuntu. You can leave it as unallocated space, and start with the Ubuntu installation process. At one point, there will be an option that will say *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7*, like this:
[image]
This option will not present itself if there is no free space available in your hard disk. So when you choose this option, it will only use up that free space. However, in your current situation, you won't be able to select that option, it will probably say "unusable space" or something like that. Here is why:

I'm guessing this is how it looks like to you in EaseUS:

```
*:SYSTEM               Primary
C:                     Primary
*:              Unallocated 15GB Space
D: Recovery            Primary
*: HP_TOOLS            Logical
```

To cut down on some of the explanation:

- You won't be able to create that space as a Primary partition, because you can't have more than three Primary partitions + one (or more) Logical partition. This is a limitation of the MSDOS partitioning.
- You won't be able to create that space as a Logical partition, because all Logical partitions have to be next to each other, one after the other. And in your situation, the D (Recovery) drive is between your free space and HP_TOOLS (which is the other Logical drive).

So you have several options:

1. Move the Recovery partition to be above the free space, so it would look like this:

   ```
   *:SYSTEM               Primary
   C:                     Primary
   D: Recovery            Primary
   *:              Unallocated 15GB Space
   *: HP_TOOLS            Logical
   ```

   Now, you'll be able to create a partition from that free space (or as I said, you can leave it as free space, and choose that *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7* when installing Ubuntu). To "move" the partition in EaseUS, just right click on the Recovery partition, and select the first option "Resize/Move partition" . In that window, you need to slide that box (indicated below) to the left most side:
   [image]

   Once you do that and hit OK, you'll be able to create a partition from that free space. **NOTE: moving a partition might take a very long time, like 2 hours.**
2. You can convert your Recovery partition to a Logical partition. That way, it would look like this:

   ```
   *:SYSTEM               Primary
   C:                     Primary
   *:              Unallocated 15GB Space
   D: Recovery            Logical
   *: HP_TOOLS            Logical
   ```

   Now, you'll be able to create a partition from that free space. However, I do not know what are the implications of converting the Recovery partition to Logical, so I don't recommend this method.
3. You can delete the HP_TOOLS partition altogether. From what I've read, you can recreate it on a USB drive later. So, when you delete the HP_TOOLS partition (right click and delete partition), your layout would look like this:

   ```
   *:SYSTEM               Primary
   C:                     Primary
   *:              Unallocated 15GB Space
   D: Recovery            Primary
   *:              Unallocated 100MB Space
   ```

*Even though it might say "Logical" next to the free spaces, just ignore it.* Now, you can create a partition from that 15GB free space, because it will be the only Logical partition. As for the deleted HP_TOOLS partition, I believe it is only 100MB, so you can just leave it there. If you really *really* need this free 100MB space, you can move the Recovery partition to the right, which will move the 100MB to the left to merge it with the 15GB space. However, again, moving the partitions will take a long time.

I recommend the last method.
By the way, you can check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/149829/52726, it's about the same thing. However, I did not flag your question as a duplicate because you are using EaseUS, so I thought you'd prefer it over the partitioning feature that you can use while installing Ubuntu, since I'm guessing you are new to Ubuntu.

Good luck!