# How do install Ubuntu over Windows7?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 but I didn't see the windows outlined by the numbered installation walk-through:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

I was never given an option to install Ubuntu over Windows and wipe it out. How do I achieve this? I am running a new Dell XPS with Windows 7 Premium.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Is your XPS an Ultrabook? Then this may apply.    http://askubuntu.com/questions/329059/no-partitions-showing-during-installation/329115#329115

Comment: I don't have experience with a Windows system, but if you have any other version of Ubuntu already installed on your system, then it will definitely ask you whether you want to **"Replace the [previous version] with [new version]"**. Windows and Ubuntu have different file systems and hence Ubuntu might not be able have to identify it. Hence You might not be getting the option to **Install Ubuntu over Windows**. But again that's what I expect as I have not done the same on Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option "Replace Windows with Ubuntu". 
If there isn't one you can do it manually by choosing option "Something else" so you can erase Windows partition and make an Ubuntu one. There are numerous guides on how to do that.

Comment: Are you saying there is an option in the Ubuntu partition to uninstall the Win7 partition?

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with your question, there are two possible options you may select from while in **Installation type** step:

***1. Erase disk and install Ubuntu:*** This will erase entire Hard disk and install Ubuntu.

***2. Something else:*** This will show you the partitions or volumes available on your hard disk. You can select the volume in which Windows is installed, format and delete the partition and install Ubuntu.

Both these ways will help you get rid of Windows and have only Ubuntu in your system.