# how to modify fstab for windows ntfs drive, and removing RAID

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs, raid, fstab

I am trying to automatically mount 2 drives that have been previously formatted in windows and have all my research (so I am trying to tread carefully), but running into some questions.

The HD are NTFS formatted, and in fstab I already see them, but they do not mount automatically:

/dev/sdb1     /media/sdb1/  linux_raid_member defaults    0     0

/dev/sdc1     /media/sdc1/  linux_raid_member defaults    0     0

So Ubuntu thinks this is a RAID setup, but the drives are not in RAID and have different information (legacy from two other drives that I was attempting to set up in RAID).

So wonder if by just changing the line information to:

UUID=xxxxx  /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1 ntfs-3g defaults locale=en_US.utf8 0 0

UUID=xxxxx  /dev/sdc2 /media/sdc1 ntfs-3g defaults locale=en_US.utf8 0 0

### xxxxx = the actual UUID.

would be enough or do I need to do something different?

Also: 
A) Not sure if each drive should have its own locale, or they can share locales?
B) Would removing the linux_raid_member section affect the reading of the drives?

Any input would be much appreciated.

---

Thank you, 
I first setup the directories under home:

```
    /home/data/one
    /home/data/two
```

Next, edited fstab:

```
   UUID=xxxx /home/data/one  auto   defaults 0 0
   UUID=xxxx /home/data/two  auto   defaults 0 0
```

However, when using

```
    sudo mount -a
```

I still get that the directories do not exist. 
When restarting ubuntu - at startup I get the problem mounting the drives" however, I cannot tell if it is because it cannot identify the drives, or if it is because of problems with the code line in fstab.  Any thoughts?

Should I use ntfs-3g instead of auto, for example?

Comment: see this on removing RAID meta-data: http://askubuntu.com/questions/329059/no-partitions-showing-during-installation/329115#329115

Comment: Just resolved the issue --- was making the folders in the wrong place (home) where they need to be in (/) or "file system" - and then from there they can be moved to "home".

Answer (score 0):

No: you either specify the device name (/dev/sdb1) *or* the UUID.  You can't specify both.  And don't add the `locale` column either -- fstab is a fixed-format file that requires exactly six whitespace-separated fields on each line.

I think it ought to be sufficient to replace `linux_raid_member` with `auto` on both lines:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1/ auto defaults 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/sdc1/ auto defaults 0 0
```

Also, make sure /media/sdb1 and /media/sdc1 directories exist, then try mounting with

```
sudo mount -a
```

If it works, it should work on next boot.

Comment: See below for problems...