# Dual-booting Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 7. Having problems

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I was running Ubuntu 12.10 alongside my Windows 7 Home Premium using WUBI. I was not able to figure out how to upgrade to 13.04. Then after I found out WUBI had been discontinued and it might cause problems, I ultimately decided to uninstall my whole Linux system and re install with 13.04 from a boot disk. Just to make sure I did everything right, I watched this video[Dual Boot Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7 (easiest way)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeSaVzyPY8k) on youtube on how to do it. (It's pretty Idiot proof...or so I thought...)

The only thing I have done different is I used the default Windows Disk Burner instead of image burn and I have a 64 bit system instead of a 32 bit.

I have gone into the BIOS and changed it to start with the boot disk and I get to setting up Ubuntu. When I get to the "How do I want to install?" page I don't have the option to run alongside Windows 7. I have the option to run inside Windows 7.

I don't want to replace my Windows 7 mainly for school and work reasons (have to have office and IE etc...) but I also really like Ubuntu. I pick the run inside option because that's the closest one to running alongside and my computer restarts and my disk tray pops out. then it reboots into Windows and I have to start the process over.

I have downloaded the .iso twice from the Ubuntu download page and have made two seperate boot disks and the same thing happens on both of them.

Is there anyone who can help me?

My current Windows 7 system is as follows:

- HP Pavilion dv7
- 1 TB hard drive
- Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit)
- Intel Core i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30 GHz
- 8 gigs of Ram

Thanks for any help you can provide! Thanks!

Comment: My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: There are several solutions, but could you use a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and write `fdisk -l` then edit your question and paste the results?

Comment: I could except I can't even get to a place to do that. I think the problem is something with the .iso file since everything works perfectly up until the "How do I want to install?" page. By the way, what's the difference between running alongside and running inside?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a second partition on your hard drive here are a couple of links to help you out.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309170.aspx

Those should help you create a new partition
It is not actually important that you format the new free space, but make sure you name it something clearly identifiable from your pre-existing windows partition. Whenever you use the cd to install reformat the new partition that has nothing on it to a gnu/linux format ext4 should work without issue. Whenever you get installed you will be able to access your windows files from ubuntu but you won't have access to your ubuntu files from windows. If you need access from windows you would have to use a "fat" format.