# Installing ubuntu 13.04 on HP G series

Tags: hp

More specifically the [G6-1344EA](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fh10025.www1.hp.com%2Fewfrf%2Fwc%2Fdocument%3Fdocname%3Dc03136265%26lc%3Den&ei=Hd5BUvnUKtHOswaflIGoBg&usg=AFQjCNFF50ZI2DI70IVsVj_n5kMKWfGazg&sig2=uIa6RxJMoT0aZbzaKyrGdw), alongside windows 7 64-bit.

Installing from an 8GB memory stick, when installing it will reboot after the screen where you choose if alongside windows 7, or ontop of etc. After restarting it will boot back into the try it now. Installed using the same memory stick onto a standard desktop successfully, so not sure what's happening, any tips?

**

> I think I found a fix, I will finish uploading the video, try it and change this message if it worked.

**

HP install all 4 of the allowed 4 partitions on their laptops (Local disk C:, Recovery D:, and HP_TOOLS G:, leaving not enough for Ubuntu (or any other OS). Removing HP_TOOLS (fingers crossed) fixes this.

Comment: @Braiam It was plugged in the whole time, am I meant to unplug it?

Comment: I mean, it's not installing, I only get to the menu where I get to choose if I install alongside or ontop of

Comment: I want to install, and keep windows 7. When I choose the option to do this, my laptop just reboots back into the memory stick and starts the process again.

Comment: I made a video, I'm currently uploading it. [here when it's finished](http://youtu.be/nlNMJhX7MBw)

Comment: I recommend you read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the USB drive. The computer still sees the USB as a boot device and chooses that route first.

Comment: When I click the continue button on the screen where you choose how ubuntu is installed (inside/replacing), it will restart.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your bios,→ Reboot and hold the left <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key down.

Go to the **BOOT** tab, "Click Tab", and check your boot order.

Change the **Boot Order** so that the Hard Drive boots first; and then USB or CD/DVD drive.
This way if there is a bootable partition on the Hard Drive it will boot there first.→ Scroll ↓= F6, Scroll ↑ = F7 (on my lap top anyway). "Scroll" to selection, "Highlight" it, and move it to where you want it in the **"Boot Order"**...

Save and Exit: = F10, (on my lap top).

(How to change the BOOT ORDER should be at the bottom of your boot screen...)

Hope this helps... Good Luck!