# How to install Ubuntu 13.10 on Hybrid Disk alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am having trouble installing Ubuntu 13.10 on HP Envy 4-1046tx ultrabook. When i bought this, it came with windows 7 pre-installed, but i upgraded it to 8 and now recently to 8.1. But somehow, i feel 8.1 is slower or something went wrong with the upgrade and made my system slow. I want to try Dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 with windows 8.1

The system recovery drive has windows 7 recovery files. SSD has 4GB allocated to windows 8 (i think for hibernation/rapid start). 25GB of SSD is free and i want to install ubuntu on this SSD pointing it to "/"

I will also shrink the windows partition (the only other partition available apart from recovery & SSD) to free up 100GB and allocate this space to "/home" during ubuntu installation.

I tried the above steps while on windows 8, but not successful. Ubuntu installation went fine, but the grub was not loaded. I tried to deploy linux via EasyBCD, but after that also, selecting linux in the boot would load grub on command prompt and do nothing.

While ubuntu installation, i also deleted the raid drivers with sudo dmraid -rE, but still ubuntu didnt recognize my windows.

I think i am missing some steps, so this time i want to do it right with proper info before starting the process.

My requirements:

- dual boot Ubuntu with windows 8.1
- c:\ shrinked windows with 300GB on sda1, 100GB for /home on sda1 & ubuntu installed on 25GB SSD volume sda2 (this is mSata i think)
- GRUB or EFI that helps me load both OS properly without breaking anything
- SWAP partition can be added if needed on sda1 (4gb?)?

I have backed up my drive and have a 16GB usb3.0 with ubuntu loaded. I hope i have mentioned everything i need and know.. All i  need now is some guidance and what to do right so that this installation goes as planned :) 
[Partition Map](https://plus.google.com/116802337806785675763/posts/5GiPBuWX8Qn)

Answer (score 1):

You have a BIOS install, not UEFI. And your main hard drive has all 4 primary partitions used.
You need to run the dmraid commands on both drives and make sure you have turned off hibernation and Intel SRT caching in Windows. Not sure with Windows 7 if it is like 8 or not.

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdb
```

[My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Was system UEFI booting before? That would leave gpt data on drive also that causes issues. Otherwise just be sure to boot in BIOS mode even if system is UEFI capable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need small EFI partition like here:
http://main.makeuseoflimited.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/dual_ubuntu_efi_partitions.jpg

Comment: I think i already have 199mb partition like this installed by windows 8? i will upload my disk partition picture in a while.. i have it on my g+, can i share it here directly ?