# Ubuntu 13.10 dual boot installation with Win 7 problems

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

Well, I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 and I want to install it alongside with Windows 7, but when restarted my PC with the DVD in and appears the installation menu, there's no dual boot installation option.

PS: I have installed (alongside with Windows 7) Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) and it also appears as normal program in Windows 7.

I don't understand why it doesn't recognize Windows 7.

I'm a noob.

Comment: just start the installation...

Comment: @user251442 First 11.04 as reached EOL and should not be used, you will not be able to get any updates for 11.04 not even security.

Comment: Any install inside Windows is wubi. That is being discontinued and last supported version is 12.04. Most Windows 7 systems use all 4 primary partitions allowed with MBR(msdos) partitioning. So you have to make room for an extended partition and then can have an unlimited number of logical partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There Will be not be option for dual boot in the installation menu but you have to install it first in a different partition or alongside(or where you want to give the mount point.)

After the complete installation when you would boot up again, you will get options in the gurb bootloader to choose between the windows and ubuntu.

If you get any problem attach a screen shot. Njoy  ubuntu.

Comment: Installation Guide: http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/