# Installing ubuntu with Windows - installer can't see partitions

Tags: system-installation, partitioning

I know there were many questions in this area, but i'm still unable to install ubuntu without formating whole disk.

I've got Windows 8 and 4 partitions
100 GB - windows
30 GB
117 GB
418 GB
and
30GB unallocated space I made in Windows Disk Management Tool (I thought Ubuntu will see it)

Ubuntu (Live) can perfectly see all partitions and I have access to it:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                       LABEL
sda             698,7G                                  
├─sda1 ntfs       100M /media/ubuntu/Zastrzeżone przez  Zastrzeżone przez system
├─sda2 ntfs     100,9G /media/ubuntu/8EF8F38DF8F37237   
├─sda3 ntfs        30G /media/ubuntu/10A28513A284FF0A   
├─sda4 ntfs     117,7G /media/ubuntu/Muzyka             Muzyka
└─sda5 ntfs     418,4G /media/ubuntu/Nowy               Nowy
sdb              14,7G                                  
└─sdb1 vfat      14,7G /cdrom                           EJZEPEN
sr0              1024M                                  
loop0  squashfs 842,7M /rofs
```

But installer sees disk like that: (see screenshot)

[image]

I want to install Ubuntu on 30GB unallocated space or make a new partition out of "Nowy" partition without without formatting it.

```
sudo fdisk -lu

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4f693826

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *        2048      206847      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          206848   211765247   105779200   42  SFS
/dev/sda4       211765248  1465147119   626690936   42  SFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.8 GB, 15805186048 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1921 cylinders, total 30869504 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *         128    30869503    15434688    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Are partitions in Windows still basic or did you convert to dynamic which does not work with Linux? With MBR(msdos) partitioning you cannot have more than 4 primary partitions. Windows often does not use the extended & logical partitions but a proprietary dynamic partition scheme. Or is Windows 8 still hibernated? Post this if SFS then dynamic. sudo fdisk -lu

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1   *         128    30869503    15434688    c      W95     FAT32 (LBA)

Comment: Fdisk is not showing sda at all? Does Winows say dynamic for partitions?

Comment: I included output in my question, Windows isn't hibernated, now i don't know if it says Dynamic

Comment: SFS means in Windows it is dynamic partitions. You must undo the dynamic partitions. Windows does not have a way, or its way is full back up and restore to only 4 primary partitions. Some third party Windows tools may work, but you will want to get to 3 NTFS partitions and one extended partition, so backup & delete what you can first as it may make conversion easier. Tools that may work (not sure if free versions do dynamic conversion). http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html Link to one: http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Comment: Then you can install if you do not have the 4 primary partition issue or: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Is it all possible without reinstalling windows?

Comment: Only if the Windows tools work to undo the SFS or dynamic partitions.