# Not able to boot in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

I am pretty new to ubuntu, 2 days back I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in widows. I was told that 12.04 is very obsolete version. so I deleted (literally `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Del`) Ubuntu directory and downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04. Now the problem is when I start the computer, I see a prompt whether I want to boot in Windows or Ubuntu, but when I select Ubuntu it shows some error message - obviously since I have deleted the files. But I am not able to see the prompt for Ubuntu 14.04.

Please help. If you need more information regarding this I'll give it in comments.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Error : Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.                                         Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.

Comment: Wait.. this appears when you select Ubuntu or Windows? In post you write, that this message appears when you select Ubuntu

Comment: This message appears when i select ubuntu

Comment: You said in Windows which is wubi? While wubi is still available, it really is only supported with 12.04. Better to do a full partitioned install. But almost all Windows 7 systems use all 4 primary partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Simply uninstall program Ubuntu in Windows and install Ubuntu from live CD.

Comment: @FilipSohajek instead of uninstalling the ubuntu, i have delete all the files. Now there is entry in boot file, due to which i see the ubuntu. I could see the same when I have not installed 14.04

Answer (score 0):

**Short:**

Forget about Wubi, restore Windows bootloader, prepare partitions and install Ubuntu 14.04 in a normal way.

**Detailed:**

Boot from Windows 7 DVD and after choosing language options, start the console:
*Repair your computer* -> *Use recovery tools...* -> *Command prompt*. In the
console run the following commands to re-install Windows bootloader:

`bootrec /fixmbr`

`bootrec /fixboot`

Reboot and that's it! Now You should have only normal Windows bootloader, no mess after Wubi.

Then prepare partitions for Ubuntu. You can shrink Windows NTFS partition under Windows and let the Ubuntu installer use free space, or you can let the installer handle whole process for you. It is wide topic, but is is not very complicated, so there is nothing to worry about. There is no reason to re-write official Ubuntu documentation here, just read and follow [Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) and everything will be clear and easy.