# Setting up partitions when installing Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I have a 2 terabyte sata drive:

- The first partition is a 100 Mb system reserved.
- The second is a primary partition 18.58 Gb. It has no description and no options on right click. Everything is greyed out. Is that a restore partition?
- The third partition is a 745 Gb C drive healthy boot page file win 7 partition.
- The forth partition is a storage area 1099 Gb.

Should I start by shrinking c-drive to lets say 150 Gb? If I do what is the next step.

I have downloaded a 14.04.1 ISO file. I can put that on a USB or DVD. After shrink windows 7 partition should I create another partition for ubuntu or will i take care of that during install?

What about any other partitions I might want to make or need?

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Depending on your usage pattern one, both, or neither of the data and Windows partitions might  be resized. This can be done using Windows `administrative tools` or using `gparted`. Purchasing a cheap hard disk for Ubuntu is another easy option.

Comment: Use Windows to shrink the Windows partition and reboot to let it update to new size and run chkdsk. But do not create partitions with Widnows as it will convert to dynamic partitions which does not work with Linux. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 options if you don't want lose your previous data or OS.

You need know that the maximum number of primary partitions on a disk is 4.

So, this is what I would do :

1. Backup contents of DATA partition
2. In Ubuntu installer select Custom partitioning
3. Erase DATA Partition
4. Create an extended partiotion and inside of the extended partition I would create the following partitions:

A. DATA PARTITION

B. SWAP PARTITION for Ubuntu (4 GB for example)

C. EXT PARTITION for Ubuntu O.S

Comment: Thank you. This is sort of my experimentle disk...But I like the idea of getting ahold of another cheap disk.   And I do like the partician scheeme.  Ill Shrink WIndows 7 Partician reboot and go from there.