# Dual booting windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I'm pretty new to using Ubuntu and I've been trying to dual boot my computer with Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I currently have windows 7 running on my laptop. My laptop is an HP envy 15t. When I go to dual boot Ubuntu I get a screen that say "This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do?" It then gives me the option to erase disk and install Ubuntu and something else. I go to click something else, which is what I am suppose to do, and I go and look for the partition I created and it doesn't show up at all. I'm not sure what to do so if anyone could help me that would be great

Comment: Was this originally a Windows 8 system with gpt partitioning? If so Windows converts to MBR but leaves a backup gpt partition table. Linux tools then see both MBR and gpt and get lost.  Other reasons: http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html

Comment: This was not. I have had this laptop for about a month now. It can with windows 7 installed in it

Comment: Then you may have the HP standard issue of all 4 primary partitions are used. Even if you have unallocated space you cannot create another partition. You have to backup & delete one. Many just do that to the HP_tools partition and restore as a logical partition.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu  and: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/Hp-Tools-Partion/td-p/228360

Answer (score 0):

i would say you that just avoid two option and install ubuntu alongside windows 7,sometimes it shows these types of error messages so no need to worry.one better way to use any other os other then windows you can use vmware or virtual box.