# Replacing WIndows 7 with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I'm using HP Pavilion g6 running Windows 7, I would like to uninstall windows and replace it with Ubuntu. I know the installer has an option, there are virtually no mportant files on Windows 7, I just want to know if any risks will stop the PC booting.

EDIT: No, I cannot run alongside Windows 7 alongside, the only other option is "Inside" Windows 7. I don't want Windows 7.

Comment: **Backup and or copy the few important files you have into an external device.** Boot from the Live DVD/USB. Choose "Try Ubuntu without installing." Check everything works. Then install if Ubuntu works fine. I cannot guarantee it, but most probably the PC will boot Ubuntu when the installation is done. The reason you don't get the option to install alongside is because your computer came with 4 primary partitions. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: I have ZERO important files. I already tried without installing. Should I just replace Win 7?

Comment: Remember Ubuntu does not run Windows programs like itunes. If you have done your research and know that Ubuntu has all the programs you will need. Then do it. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm doing the replacement now! Wish me luck! -Im not an apple person, so I don't need iTunes.

Comment: Good luck! Here is something to read while Ubuntu installs. http://askubuntu.com/search?q=HP+Pavilion+g6

Comment: Please delete the question as this is not likely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need any files currently on your laptop then restart, enter BIOS, set CD-ROM as first boot device, insert Ubuntu DVD and restart again. Computer will boot of off Ubuntu DVD and then you just follow the wizard to do a clean install.

If your laptop's hardware is OK then there is no risk of it not booting so no worries there.

Here you can find it all explained: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

During the installation you will need to be connected to the internet. Otherwise your sources.list will not be updated. (although that can be easily fixed @ repogen.simplylinux.ch. After that, the only thing you need to worry about is that if you choose to reinstall windows you will have to pay for it again unless you have a restore CD.

In case of the unlikely event that Ubuntu fails to boot, you should have a backup device capable of browsing the internet so you can look up the solution.

source: personal experience. I recently got rid of windows 7, after saving some important files to google drive. My computer runs purely on Ubuntu right now.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download the latest Ubuntu ISO http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/ You can choose either Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS or Ubuntu 14.10, choose the LTS version if you want a really secure, stable version.

Step 2: Acquire a USB stick or a Black CD/DVD. You can then follow this guide to make a Ubuntu installer on the USB or DVD. I recommend you use a USB, much faster than a CD/DVD and they usually result in fewer issues.

Make a CD/DVD: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Make a USB: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

After you have done this backup any important files that you have.

Reboot your PC and while it's booting mash the 'F' key that brings up your boot menu, for most computers it's F12, F10, F4 or Backspace but it could be any 'F' key. Select either the USB stick or CD/DVD and the Ubuntu installer will start, from here you can follow this guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

I recommend you 'Download updates while installing' and 'Install this third-party software' to do this simply have your PC plugged into a wired connection, if you are using WiFi in the top right corner you can select your WiFi there and connect to a network, I recommend you connect to a network first thing. When you get to the storage section just select 'Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu' finish the installation and there you go, enjoy Ubuntu. I hope this helped.

P.S. Don't be put off Ubuntu 14.10, It is stable but if you want the most rock-solid version choose 14.04.1 LTS, if you want the newest features and technology choose 14.10.