# Ubuntu 14.10 doesn't recognize 20 GB partition in Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

So I've used Ubuntu before, maybe a few years back and I don't remember it being this difficult to install. Anyway I put Ubuntu 14.10 on a flash drive with pendrivelinux, that part is done, no issues.

I fragmented the disk, and I set aside a 20 GB partition for Ubuntu so I can dual boot. Booted back into windows twice just so it could recognize what I did. Went to install 14.10 and the partition I made didn't show up during install. I only get the prompt to erase hard drive or do a manual partition with Ubuntu.

There is a 21.5 GB space that says unusable when I go with that, but I don't want to mess anything up with my Windows. This should be simple.

[image]

Comment: In the ubuntu installer, click 'Try Ubuntu', and open GParted. Could you add a screenshot of what is shown? (You can use http://imgur.com)

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what's shown in GParted. [img]http://i.imgur.com/HvjF2Lg.png?1[/img]

Comment: possible duplicate of [My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [screenshot you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSEKY.png) I think that the problem is that **there may be only 4 primary partitions** on your hard drive and you already have all of them there. Therefore you cannot just easily install Ubuntu because the installation script cannot make any new partition and it do not know what to do so it just offers you only possible solutions. **In my opinion you have to delete one manually** (and then you can add new extended partition instead) in order to install Ubuntu with "one click".

All operations with partitions can be made with gparted or during installation. But be aware that your data may be lost - **backup**!

Comment: Thanks Byran. Is there a way to relocate the 20Gs back into my C drive? Also, in your opinion which one of the partitions should I delete without corrupting anything?

Comment: Yes, there is a way - if that 20GB partition is empty you can just delete it in gparted and resize the "C drive". But I would not do that yet, since you want to install Ubuntu.  
In my opinion if you have copy of installation media of your current Windows version, you can remove "RECOVERY" and "HP_TOOLS". But before you do it you should read [reasons why not to delete that partitions](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810279). **Always backup!**

Comment: The 'reasons why not to delete the partitions also included how to delete it, which should be used instead of gparted or windows disk managers. It may to help to include the instructions here, as old computer support links sometimes break.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help, I'll let you know if I encounter any issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Byran correctly said, the problem is that you have 4 partitions already. It's a problem that I also met when I installed a Linux OS alongside Windows because I had for Windows the boot partition, the local drive C, local drive D and local drive E. The solution was to delete one local drive and after that I installed the Linux OS.

So the advice is to delete manually one partition.