# Shrink volume of Primary Partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I currently run windows 8.0 and have 4 partitions. I will like to shrink the volume of my primary partition containing the win 8 OS so I can have more space to install ubuntu 14.04. My question is will it delete everything in that partition while shrinking the volume and how do I go about installing it on the new partition created.

Comment: Is this pre-installed Windows with UEFI or your install in BIOS mode with MBR partitioning and the 4 primary partition limit? http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: It's BIOS installed. Partition 1 containing win 8 has 44Gb free space, partition 2 (recovery disk) has 2.33Gb free space, partition 3 & 4 have 90Mb and 161Mb free space respectively.

Comment: With MBR you can only have 4 primary partitions. You have to delete one primary can convert to an extended partition. The extended then is like a container for as many logical partitions as you want. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

I have done this from an application in the Windows 7. It should be in win 8 also.
We can shrink the size. Afterwards "Ubuntu"can be installed with C.D. This C.D can be created by down-loading an Image file(nrg)and running a virtual drive/burning Disc. 'How to create a virtual drive' may be known from Internet.But we should be careful not to lose Windows after the installation of "UBUNTU" by deleting any partition and leaving the space without DOS partition.If space is not there we can delete unwanted files and then shrink.