# How to install Ubuntu on External HDD

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu gnome on new External HDD but I always get two error's

1. There is to many primary partitions
2. There is no root file system defined please correct partitioning menu

How can I fix this?

Comment: Be sure to also on partitioning screen change combo box at bottom to drive sdb, sdc or whatever it is to the external drive so it has boot loader. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation If you also have used all 4 primary partitions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/592778/installing-ubuntu-on-a-usb-hdd/592806#592806

Answer (score 0):

> There is to many primary partitions

Your are limited to 1 primary partition. If needed create *logical* partitions inside the primairy partition and you are able to install in it.

> There is no root file system defined please correct partitioning menu

Linux must have at least 1 partition named "/".  If you do not create that the installer will stop until you have created it.