# Installing Ubuntu on a USB HDD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, external-hdd

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB Hard Drive from my USB stick. So I went through a few similar questions on the website. However, I have a few special requirements.

1. I don't want any changes to be done to my C or D drive.
2. I want to set aside 50-100 GB on my External HDD completely dedicated to Ubuntu and all of its needs, including storage. The rest 900-950 GB (on a 1TB drive) need to be used for different purposes, along with Windows. So the two "sections" should not interfere with each other in any way.

So in short, I don't want to change my C and D drive. I want Ubuntu to stay confined to the dedicated 50-100 GB on the External USB HDD, and not mess with the rest of the space.

Also, I know nothing, absolutely nothing about Ubuntu. It is an OS I want to try out. So step by step instructions would really be appreciated.

Is this even possible? Can my computer boot from a USB device with an OS as well as other stuff not related at all to the OS? I'm really confused.

Oh and BTW I don't want Windows to be harmed in any way. It should be such that I can boot either from Windows or from Ubuntu depending on my choice.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Only Windows uses nomenclature like "C and D drive". Saying it twice doesn't make it more clear. Since Windows doesn't run off an external drive it's doubly unclear to me what you are asking. Please [edit] your question to frame it in a way that we can understand. Review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask for tips that will help us help you.

Comment: Sorry about how unclear I was.

Windows is stored on a drive, known as the C drive. I also have some more data on a second drive in the laptop, known as the D drive. Ubuntu will be stored on the external hard drive. When I boot up my computer, I want it to go to Windows unless I enter BIOS and choose to boot from my external drive. I guess since Ubuntu is on the external drive, it shouldn't interfere with the drive where Windows is stored (C drive) in any case.

Comment: Is this a newer system with UEFI or older with BIOS as the boot choice? Also only use the Something Else install option. Grub will default to internal drive or sda with any of the auto install options. If system is UEFI, but external drive is MBR (msdos) partitioned you may have issues. Post this to confirm details from Ubuntu installer in live mode from terminal: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 2):

Before Installing Ubuntu Disable Secure Boot in BIOS setting and Disable Fast Shutdown in Windows.

**Note : Read step 10 carefully, the image of step 10 doesn't show what is written**

Follow these steps :

**Step 1 :**
[Download ubuntu 14.04 from here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

**Step 2:**
[Create a bootable usb stick on windows (Click here for guide)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

**Step 3:**
Attach external HDD to USB (if not already attached)

**Step 4:**
[Download Mini Tool Partition Wizard from here](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html)

**Step 5:**
Partition properly your external HDD. Create 100 gb partition of format ext 4

**Step 6:**
Restart your system and boot from USB

**Step 7:**
Click Install

[image]

**Step 8:**
Check both boxes

[image]

**Step 9:**
Choose something else and click next

[image]

**Step 10:**
Choose /dev/sda in "Device for boot loader installation" and Select partition of type ext 4 for Ubuntu installation (its device name would be something like /dev/sdb1) and click change.

[image]

**Step 11:**
Change Mount Point To /

[image]

**Step 12:**
Press "Install Now" to continue. Rest process is easy.