# Dual boot - Windows missing after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I am posting a question and also post the answer as I don’t know other way around to help others.

I Have been struggling from last 1 month to make dual boot on my hp laptop its hp g6-2313ax, however finally I did it tonight .

My problem was, I was not getting option to select win7 and laptop was keep on booting with Ubuntu.

Below is the solution

sorry guys if i am doing anything wrong (if yes), please guide me the right way :)

Comment: Was this your issue before reinstalling Windows with fewer primary partitions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: no .... this was the first time i tried to make dual boot on my laptop though i did it on desktop multiple times without any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed win 7 normally, made 2 partition please make note its in MBR

1. 100 mb system reserved
2. 50 gigs for my win 7
3. Left rest as unallocated

Now after the installation I rebooted the and booted with bootable ubuntu USB

I am not able to see option “alongside” so selected something else

Then coming on to Ubuntu partition (doesnt matter under GPT primary or logical. But if its MBR then strongly logical)

1.20gigs mounted to / (at least 10 gigs required)

2.20gigs mounted to /home ( at least 10 gigs required)

3.10 gigs swap (double of RAM preferred)

4.You may have to create a partion in ubuntu as Fat32 if you want to move files from ubuntu to windows or vice versa (size depends on you requirement and needs. ALSO ITS NOT A MANDATE DRIVE ITS OPTIONAL.)

Then install Ubuntu make sure the directory should be /dev/sda

Once installed reboot your laptop, after reboot it will boot with Ubuntu.

Now to make windows visible we have to update the file named Grub hosted under - /etc/default/grub

To update and make the change in a statement -

**GRUB_TIMEOUT=10**

And

**GRUB_TIMEOUT_HIDDEN=10**

For this go to terminal

**Type GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 enter then**

**Type GRUB_TIMEOUT_HIDDEN=10 enter then**

**Type sudo update-grub enter**

Restart the computer I am sure you will be able to see option to choose between windows and Ubuntu

Happy ubuntuing ……….. 

I am so glad finally I did it ……yayy