# Dual Boot of windows 10& ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot

How to dual boot windows10 & ubuntu15.04? I have legacy bias mode. Every time I try to make the dual boot, it shows I have to format my full computer. I'm not sure if it'll work either. So, please help me.

Comment: If BIOS was it an upgrade from Windows 7? And Windows 7 systems use all 4 primary partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest you should follow the following steps:**

1. **Step 01:**

---

- Download EaseUS Partition(In windows) and remove the Ubuntu which is already installed in your hard disk using the software.
- Make sure to create empty space for Ubuntu in your hard disk using the Software.

---

2. **Step 02:**

---

- Make a Bootable USB drive(UBUNTU).
- Restart your computer, and press F12 for boot option and select your USB drive as boot option(make sure you are booting in legacy mode.)

---

3. **Step 03:**

---

- Just click on try Ubuntu, and on the main screen you will get an option to install Ubuntu click on that and your setup should start.
- When prompted for installation type, click on the last option(something else), and continue.

---

4. **Step 04:**

---

- Now we need to make 4 partitions.

  1. Click on unallocated space, click on new. Enter size as 48GB (you have to enter in mb), choose file system type as ext 4, mount point /, partition type primary This means Ubuntu root partition.[This is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCbEP.png)
  2. Click on unallocated space, click on new. Enter size as 2GB(probably the size of your RAM), choose primary partition, file system type SWAP.[This is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puk65.png)
  3. Click on unallocated space, click on new. Enter size 50 GB(this is main your partition), choose primary partition, file type ntfs. Continue as shown in the above images.
  4. Click on rest unallocated space, click on it. Choose ntfs as file system, partition type logical and create it. This will automatically create extended partition.Continue as shown in the above images.

---

5. **Step 05:**

   - Now continue with your normal installation, and AHA! you are done.
   - CONGRATULATIONS!