# partition table

Tags: partitioning, boot-partition

I am trying to install ubuntu on a pc which has a Windows 7 with a main partition and a recovery partition plus 2 small loader partitions. How do I create a new partition from within the install program. I am given the option to create a new partition table, however I am uncertain whether this will erase the data on the drive i.e.-the Windows installation and all my mp3's and jpg's. Help!!

Comment: Do not create a new partition table; that will indeed erase everything. Does the installer not give you the option to create another partition? Do you know if all your partitions are primary partitions?

Comment: Almost all Windows 7 systems have used all 4 primary partitions. My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Oldfred is correct, although with the caveat that the 4-primary-partition limit applies only to MBR disks; GPT disks have a limit of 128 partitions (by default; it can be raised). Windows installs to MBR only in BIOS mode, and to GPT only in EFI mode, so the two are linked, and changing from MBR to GPT will render the computer unbootable. If the disk is already GPT, you should have no problems, but then you must be careful to install Ubuntu in EFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Choose install along side windows.
A slider will appear letting you adjust the size.

(Also enter bios and make sure Secureboot is Disabled)