# Creating a extended partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I have dual booted windows 10 and ubuntu 15.04. Now I want to reinstall both OS's. The problem is that I already have 4 partitions(Ubuntu, Ubuntu swap, Windows 10, System reserved). I shrank the Windows 10 partition to create free space for a new partition to store my important files. How can I do that cause I have 4 partitions and don't know what partition to delete for a extended partition, or is there an another way?
[You can see my partitions here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2O8J.png)

Comment: You may be able to use fixparts to convert one or more primary partitions to logical. The logical must all be together as you can only have one extended partition with all logicals. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/  And Windows only boots from primary NTFS partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: What partition should I convert, does it matter actually?

Comment: Both the 9 and 246 look empty, what are they. If they really have anything you can probably delete both. I do not like moving partitions, but standard Windows installs normally use the first two on a drive.

Comment: They are actually Ubuntu partitions, one for os and the second one for swap space. In disk management it shows them as empty but other software shows them regularly.

Comment: You must *not* convert the Windows boot partition to logical form. Beyond that, it depends on the layout; the FixParts documentation describes the constraints. That said, if you're re-installing both OSes, it might be better to erase all of them and create new partitions from scratch. If your computer is from late 2011 or later, you might also consider EFI-mode installs, which will enable use of GPT, which has no 4-partition limit. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) for information on EFI-mode installs.

Comment: Currently I have to make another partition to store my important files because I have no other options of storing that data.

Comment: Can I delete ubuntu partitions since I am going to reinstall it, then fix the boot loader, then create an extended partition in windows. In the extended partition create 3 partitions for files, ubuntu and ubuntu swap. And then move my files and reinstall the windows and ubuntu. Will it work this way?

Comment: Do not use Windows to create partitions. It converts to Windows proprietary dynamic partitions and it is a one way conversion. Only use Windows to shrink or expand NTFS partitions and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk and update to new size. Then  boot Ubuntu live installer or gparted live disk and use gparted for all other partition changes.

Comment: I deleted ubuntu  partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backed up my files from ubuntu to windows, the in windows I deleted both ubuntu partitions. Then I created a partition for my files. Then reinstalled windows.
Now I have 2 partitions for windows, 1 partition for my files, and 1 partition for ubuntu. I am now waiting for ubuntu 16.04 and then I am going to install it. When installing I will create an extended partition for ubuntu and ubuntu swap partitions.