# Trying to install Ubuntu along windows 8.1, shows wrong disk partitioning

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I first had Windows 8.1 on my laptop installed and now I'm trying to add Ubuntu 15.10 and be able to dual boot. I have freed up some space and partitioned my hard drive for the Ubuntu installation.

Windows shows:

```
C:/ - 100GB (Windows 8 installation)
E:/ - 430~GB
F:/ - 430~GB
```

when I run the Ubuntu installer, it shows these:

```
/dev/sda1 - 1 MB (usage: unknown)
/dev/sda2 - 104 MB (usage: unknown)
/dev/sda3 - 105'549 MB (usage: unknown)
/dev/sda4 - 894'548 MB (usage 0 MB)
```

Even the usage is wrong as I only have the F:/ disk completely empty which is around 430 GB, the rest is used up mostly

I tried running

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

which returns:

```
    Partition table scan:
 MBR: MBR only
 BSD: not present
 APM: not present
 GPT: not present

*************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory.
*************************************************************
```

This doesn't change anything though, what can I do?

Comment: Do not convert to gpt. Do not create partitions in Windows for Linux. It may convert to Microsoft proprietary dynamic partitions which does not work with Linux. And you must have one available primary partition to allow the creation/conversion to an extended partition which then can have many logical partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Please show the *complete* output of a partitioning tool, such as `sudo fdisk -l` or `sudo parted /dev/sda print`. The truncated `gdisk` output isn't very helpful, and your summaries omit critical details.