# How many partitions will I be able to create?

Tags: lubuntu, partitioning

I'm preparing to install Lubuntu on my laptop.

I have already got stuck once, because apparently my system created two partitions (one recovery and the other I have no idea) and then I had C: and D: in Windows. So I couldn't create a new partition for Linux.

To remedy this, I removed the D: partition. My question is: will be able to install Lubuntu with all the partitions like /, /home and /swap?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only need 2 partitions for Linux.  One for the Linx OS and one for Swap.

The /home folder doesn't have to be on separate partitions.  It wouldn't hurt, but by default it's not.

You can use Gparted from the Install disk to edit your partition sizes.  If you have a large space you can use Gparted to create an extended partition.  The space in the extended partition becomes un-allocated space of which you can create any number of partitions.

So, basically you can partition the drive the way you want it.  Then on the install pick the "Something Else" for the install option.  Then you'll have a choice of specifying where you want Linux installed.  Pick the partition that you created for this install.

Comment: Well initially I created unallocated space in Windows disk management tool, but when I clicked something else in the installation, it said that the free space is unusable. So I looked online and read that you can only have 4 partitions. And as I described above, now I have 3 and I'm not sure if I'll be able to install everything that's needed successfully.

Comment: @EyfI The four partition limit is that you can only have 4 primary partitions.  If you make one of them (as I mentioned in my answer) an extended partition, you'll find that all the space in the extended partition becomes available to create as many partitions as you want.  As mentioned in my answer, you should use GParted from the install disk to create your partitions.  I'm sure you will find it easier.  It has more functionality.

Comment: So right now I have only Windows installed and ~90 GB of unallocated space. Can I create said extended partition in Windows? Or can I just install Lubuntu on the unallocated space and then create the swap partition in running Lubuntu?

Comment: @EyfI As I mentioned in the answer.  You would best create an extended partition, then you would have the ability to have many more partitions.  A swap partition is important for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you only need one primary partition to install Lubuntu.Rest all partition you can create during the installation process according to your requirement.But make sure you have sufficient large primary partition in which you are planning to install.If you need any more details specific to your problem,share a screenshot of your disk management.

Comment: I have about 90 GB of free/unallocated space. So I will be able to create all the necessary partitions (?) on it?

Comment: Yes you will be able to install all the necessary partitions,for any more help on system requirement check out  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu