# Ubuntu installation with window 7 (no windows 7 shown)

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu side by side with windows 7. While installing from usb I got the four options that
'erase disk and install Ubuntu', "encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security", "use LVM with new Ubuntu installation" and "'something else".

- which one I should select for my installation?

Comment: All those choices erase entire drive except Something Else. But most Windows 7 systems are BIOS with MBR and then have the 4 primary partition limit. And all 4 primary partitions are used. Only use Windows 7 to shrink the NTFS partition and reboot so it can run chkdsk. You may need to remove one primary so you can make many logical partitions in an extended partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

***To dual boot Ubuntu with windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10;***
Follow the following steps:

1. **Download mini tool partition.**( its free of cost and better than the disk management system of windows OS)
2. open Mini tool partition and create a 25-30 GB of allocated partition.***i suggest you to take 25 GB of partition space.***
3. **Download Universal USB installer**(this software is also free of cost)
4. Connect your USB drive to your computer and format it.
5. open Universal USB installer and select the Linux family and mount the Ubuntu.ISO image to the CD or USB drive.
6. restart your computer.
7. ass soon as you restart the device you will get a message on the screen
   example: ***a) press enter to interrupt normal setup,***
       ***b) press Del to enter into boot menu,*** 
       ***c) or some other similar message.***
8. after entering into the boot menu select the 'mass storage device from the list and hit enter'
9. Your Ubuntu setup screen will prompt select "install Ubuntu" from the list or "graphic install (if available)"
10. Immediately nothing will happen and take patience as this will take 2-5 minutes to start the setup after selecting the install option so please wait for the setup to run and do not eject the the USB drive from the computer. Many people think that their system did hang but actually it is not like what they think because setup take 2-5 approx minutes to run so don't worry and wait for a while it will definitely run after some time.
11. after all setup will start and follow the instructions.
12. the setup will ask you to select a choice out of two/three 
    a) erase disk and install Ubuntu, 
    b) Something else.
13. select b) something else and the setup will take you to the disk selection menu.

14.If you took the the partition of 25 GB double-click on the free space and then select **"swap area"** option from the list and enter the size: **3072 MB** and press continue.

15. Now again double click the  free space partition and select the "ext4" and in the second box select the **"/"** option from the list and enter the size: **7168 MB**
16. follow the same procedure again and make two more partition of **"/boot"** and **"/home"** both or each should have the size: **7168 MB**
17. Press continue. If you are asked to provide a host name the just type **"ubuntu"** and proceed further.

*The installation process of Ubuntu is much easy as compared to other distributions of Linux. But if still you you have any doubt or error while installing you can contact me or send me a mail at: mailrizvi786rediffmail.com*

Comment: I suggest no /boot unless you have a server or LVM/RAID. And unless hibernating you and if you have 4GB of RAM you need very little swap like 2GB. And if only allocating 25GB, you may be better with just / & swap. Only if allocating a lot more then keep / at 25GB and make /home large.