# Problem in installing Ubuntu on a win 7 lenovo laptop upgraded to windows 10

Tags: uefi, bios

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Z570,it shows the following error message while trying to install ubuntu

https://goo.gl/photos/tAKzW5vzSQND42a88

Please help!

Comment: It looks like you have a newer UEFI system, but had Windows7 in BIOS boot mode. If you convert to gpt then you will break Windows. But if Windows is BIOS then you have to have MBR partitioning with the 4 primary partition limit. Make sure Windows fast start up or always on hibernation is off. Use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition. Reboot immediately to make sure it runs chkdsk. And have an available primary partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Also go into the BIOS and select "legacy before UEFI" so you can boot in legacy mode for the install.

Comment: Why does it say Debian?

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding to my question! After some research I decided to uninstall Windows and join the ubuntu community for real. Go ubuntu!