# 16.04 'Alongside' Windows 7 install option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, system-installation

In previous installs, I saw a line item option to install 16.04 alongside windows:

[image]

A failed attempt to boot and install Ubuntu (screen freeze) was followed with a Ubuntu USB attempt: the 'alongside' install option is not present:
[image]

Exploration of 'Something Else' menus result in wiping the existing Windows install (would like to avoid this and have a dual-boot system).

## QUESTION

1. Is it possible and what are the steps to restore the 'install
   alongside Windows' option?
2. Is this problem unique to Windows 7? or 16.04?

Procedures, Reference, Suggestions and lessons-learned are appreciated.

Comment: Could you boot from the LiveDVD/USB and select "Try Ubuntu without installing" option and then open Gparted and take a screenshot of partitions in Gparted. Then edit the question and add that image to your question?

Comment: Windows 7 systems almost always use all 4 primary partitions. My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try to defrag Windows first and then install Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you are selecting to boot legacy or uefi.  I have found that if you are selecting to boot uefi then sometimes the ubuntu install will not detect the windows install when trying to install ubuntu as a dual boot option.

Reboot your pc - enter 1 time boot menu while booting (usually f12) - select legacy boot if possible and then your boot media and try to install ubuntu.

Good luck

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. In Windows 7: Defrag the volume
2. [Shrink thevolume in Win7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)
3. Boot Ubuntu CD or USB