# "Install Ubuntu alongside windows 10" option missing during Ubuntu 16.04.1 Installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have Windows 10 64 bit installed on my HDD of Dell Inspiron 5559. When I booted from my USB to install Ubuntu at a point it detects that windows 10 is installed in my HDD but doesn't give an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. It only provides option to format HDD and install Ubuntu only and "Something Else".
Before installation of Ubuntu I properly shut down Windows 10 and I have created an unallocated space for Ubuntu. Windows 10 is installed in BIOS mode legacy. As already mentioned I have a HDD. 
The result of `sudo parted -l` is

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  525MB  524MB  primary  ntfs         boot
2      525MB   157GB  157GB  primary  ntfs
3      157GB   579GB  422GB  primary  ntfs
4      579GB   839GB  260GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ADATA USB Flash Drive (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4041MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      32.8kB  4041MB  4041MB  primary  fat32        boot
```

I am new to Ubuntu so, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Often related to Windows fast start up or always on hibernation. It is not just shutdown Windows as then it is hibernated, but you must turn off hibernation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Some systems also need UEFI Secure boot off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but none of the methods worked. I already had UEFI Secure boot turned off but even after turning off fast start up and completely turning off hibernation also the result was the same.

Comment: What brand/model system?  Standard AHCI configuration in UEFI? WIndows 10 pre-installed so UEFI/gpt configuration. Standard hard drive, not any of the newer SSDs? Post this in first post so you can format it correctly: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: You have the 35 year old BIOS/MBR config with the 4 primary partition limit. You need to convert one primary partition to an extended and then you can have an unlimited number of logical partitions. Do not create partitions with WIndows as it will convert to dynamic which is not compatible. My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu
Good advice on how to handle all four primary partitions used. - srs5694
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1686440

Comment: Thanks those measures worked but now I am not being able to boot into Windows but I can boot into Ubuntu. The problem is further discussed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/861923/windows-10-not-booting-up-after-ubuntu-16-04-1-installation).