# Partition for Ubuntu shows as 'unusable'

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 64-bit laptop with windows 10 installed.
I am using this [everydaylinuxuser tutorial](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) to install Ubuntu.

When I come to point of selecting the drive to install Ubuntu on I'm not able to do this.

[image: that + sign is disable.please help.]

Comment: You need to create a partition first if you do manual partitioning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: @Pilot6 It's not a duplicate of the question you suggested. The question you mentioned is about `installing Ubuntu alongside a non-UEFI OS` like WindowsXP.

Comment: It seems that your disk has MBR partition table and that already contains four primary partitions, which is maximum allowed and does not let you create more partitions for Ubuntu. The only way to continue would be: Backup the contents of sda3 and sda4, delete those partitions, create extended partition in the free space and logical partitions for the former contents of sda3 and sda4. Then install Ubuntu. Or install Ubuntu on sdb, if that is an option.

Comment: @ridgy I think you are right.Thanks for suggesting.can you tell me exactly what I should do?

Comment: @Pilot6 This is not duplicate question

Comment: You need to create a partition first by `gparted`.

Comment: More a duplicate of this: My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @Pilot6 can you mention whole process that you want to share with us?

Answer (score 0):

There are some (free) Windows programs to make logical partitions out of primary ones, see e.g [AOMEI](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/convert-primary-to-logical.html), [MACRORIT](http://macrorit.com/help/how-to-convert-primary-partition-to-logical.html) or [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/convert-primary-to-logical.htm). I never used one of them, so I cannot tell how secure they are. There is also a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0Dr7UGuBIw) - and many more of them.

If you find one of that useful, run it from windows, then convert the partition *after the free space* (in your image: `sda3`) to `logical`, which will create an extended partition containing the logical partitions `sda3`and `sda4`. Try to decrease the size of the last partition (as there are ~100G free), so you have free space in the extended partition - and Ubuntu should present this as possible for installation.

**And always be sure to have a valid backup of your valuable data!**