# Can't dual boot my PC with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS today and I tried to dual boot it with window 7, but when I start installing Ubuntu there is no option to install Ubuntu alongside window 7.  I have 119 gb allocated. How can I install as dual boot?

Comment: Windows 7 systems are usually BIOS with MBR partitioning and use all 4 primary partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why that option is not available but if you can choose "somaething else" you can partition your disk yourself and allocate the amount of disk you want to the Ubuntu installation.

Alternatively, when you boot up from live usb, you can run a tool called "gparted" which is included in the live image to shrink the partition with Windows to the volume you want and then what is left can be used for installing Ubuntu.

Just make sure then carefully where to install the bootloader.

I have done this a couple of times myself but I suggest that you wait for others to come along and hopefully provide you with more detailed step by step instruction if you are not sure about what to do.

In the meantime you can read more here:
[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

You can have look as well at https://help.ubuntu.com/ and search in the searchbox for what you are looking for.

Good luck!