# Triple boot Windows 7 64 bit, Windows 7 32 bit and Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have installed windows 7 both 32 and 64 bit as you see on the screenshot.. whereas there are 3 partitions already set up.

Now the issue is I need to install Ubuntu and Ubuntu can only hv 4 partitions due to which I am unable to make what I need!!!

As I am learning a database course I need Ubuntu to have almost 10 partitions.. which I know I can make under an extended partition but here I have free space but can't work on it due to the partition limit.

Can someone please help I need this fixed asap

Comment: "as you see on the screenshot" What screenshot? NVM, doesn't matter.

Comment: Have you used all 4 primary partitions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: SORRY , I could not add the screenshot as did not have enough reputation and I have 3 partitions that are used.. One with the boot loader I guess and the other 2 partitions with each of windows 7 os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ". . . whereas there are 3 partitions already set up . . . and Ubuntu can only hv 4 partitions due to which I am unable to make what I need!!!"

Last I checked 3 was less than 4. Make an extended partition and put anything you want in logical partitions inside it.

Ubuntu does not limit the number of partitions, that is the nature of your hardware. Anyway it is only a limitation on the number of "primary" partitions, not of total partitions.

From Windows, shrink your windows partitions as much as practical. If you need to shrink them more than they will shrink easily, there are ways to to defeat the stuff MS does to make it difficult, and shrink them further, but that is another subject. At any rate shrink them ENOUGH. For whatever you want to install.

Then boot an Ubuntu live disk and use the program "gparted". Make an extended partition of all available space (if you didn't shrink Windows efficiently you may waste some hd space, but you can fix that when it becomes pressing). Then make "logical partions" as you wish for what you plan to install. Or you can put that last step off and do it as you install each OS if you plan on more than 3.

Comment: So the 4th partition that I would make can be a extended partition? I was doubting whether Ubuntu would boot from the extended partition , under the extended partition create the swap,root, and the other logical drives?

Comment: Yes. It does. Yes. Respectively. Only antiquated operating systems and one that deliberately try to make it hard to multi-boot for commercial reasons won't boot from a "logical" partition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!! 
I created the 4th partition as a extended partition and then divided that partition into root ,swap and the needed logical partitions using gparted from the livecd of Ubuntu n then installed Ubuntu on the root..!! Windows did give me a boot error.. but used my usb to repair windows..!! Everything seems to be working fine for now :)