# Can't see my partitions while installing ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04. I have a `win 7` in `partition C` and private files in partition D. So I shrank partition D with windows OS and made a `partition E` with 50 GB free space on it. Then I turned my hard drive to basic. Now I want to install Ubuntu in `partition E`. But While installing Ubuntu, it doesn't recognize my partitions and shows it like one partition. But in Ubuntu live I can see my partitions and files well.

What's the problem? Can you help me fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Almost all Windows 7 installs used all 4 primary MBR(msdos) partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu Some that use Windows to create partitions also convert from basic to a proprietary dynamic partitioning scheme. Not easy to unconvert. Are partitions shown as basic in Windows.

Comment: And for making room for Ubuntu, you shrink one or more partition but you don't create another from Windows, you just leave unallocated space (which is not a partition).

Comment: @oldfred Yes. In Disk management window all partitions are basic.

Comment: @MichaelBay That space isn't unallocated . it's a partition like my other partitions. it's name is E so I think it's allocated.

Comment: Exactly, and that's the problem. The (Ubuntu) installer never deletes partitions, it only shrinks to make room for installing Ubuntu. You can and should do it (shrink) from Windows as you did but not create another one in its place.  And if the total number of partitions is 4 no other can be create by the Ubuntu installer. Now if you were able to create another one (empty) partition, simply removing that and leaving unallocated space should let Ubuntu install.