# Cant install ubuntu. Partitioning problem windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

So, currently, I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 Laptop from a USB device, but I can't install it on a 2nd partition. I tried to create another partition on my Windows drive manager or just use some free space (130gb), but I'm not able to choose this partition or the free memory when doing the installation. I'm only able to install it to `/dev/sda`, which is not what I want obviously. Here's an image of what I see during the installation:

[image: Installation Screen]

Comment: EDIT: My current partition's are: SYTEM, Windowsd(C:) and HP_TOOLS(E:).. So i theoretically should be able to have one more partition, right?

Comment: Ubuntu (linux) does not use terms such as c: or e: to identify partitions. Normally I suggest you downsize your partitons from windows and trun off fast boot. Normally you should then be able to boot the ubuntu usb and install into free space.

Comment: My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu
But if you created partition(s) with Windows it may have converted to dynamic which can be a major issue. Are partitions in Windows shown as basic or dynamic?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Actually i know how to boot from the USB Drive, but when doing the installation i cant choose a partition to install it to... (Look picture)

Comment: @oldfred From what i can tell, its says neither of those..

Comment: If you looks in your Windows partitioning tool it should say whether basic or dynamic. Also was system originally Windows 8 or 10? Install of Windows 7 in BIOS/MBR incorrectly converts the gpt partitioning to MBR and then Linux tools do not know if MBR or gpt and fail. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @SimonM. just to clarify, both old fred and I want to see what your partitions look like from Ubuntu. Either post a screen shot from gparted or parted as oldfred asked.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I'm not using a partitioning-Tool. I was trying to do it manually, but it looks like thats not gonna lead anywhere.. I'd be thankful if someone could recommend me a good Partitioning-Tool! And the Windows was originally Windows7. That laptop is about 4 yeards old.

Comment: The ubuntu live usb has both graphical (gparted) and command line (parted) tools that work fine.