# I can't install ubuntu , due to my old hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, live-usb, badblocks

I have old hdd whenever I install ubuntu on these it crashes in between , sometimes it's called bad sector or sometimes read only file system.

I installed a month ago on same drive before this is problem also arrived but it's just installed some times.

But these time don't after many affort , what should I do ?

I think about formate my disk with `dd` command, is that help to overcome bad sector or I have to formate other way .

Is there is any way to fix from bootable pendrive, you can start linux from that and fix badsector dives then let me know.

Comment: Hi,   I would, probably - run either ntfsfix and/or fxchk on it, install ntfs-3g package, (If you now, anyway going to format it - I assume you do not have any important data on it) Or, if someone expert here has another idea, or spotted a problem in my comment, please Point that out!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes but ntfsfix also give me read only file system error and I don't have windows installed on it.

Comment: The only time I use drives with bad sectors is when I really dont care about what I am putting on it... Or I am building a computer to give someone else for free....and am never going to see them again... 1 or 2 bad sectors... i may keep it for a while (just for data storage, no OS)... but anything more than a few  bad sectors, it's a donation.

Comment: Do a Full install to USB and run off of that. It will not be as fast as a HDD but it will give you use of the computer. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280737/how-should-i-make-my-partitions-for-a-full-install-usb/1280812#1280812

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this unreliable disk and reinstall.

Comment: Is that not any way to do this in old disk , or I should have to buy new one compulsory.

Comment: It does sound like your is almost dead.  It will probably save you a lot of time just to replace.  You do not need a big or fast one so the cost can be quite low.  Goolge your computer make and model with replacing drive and see how easy it is.