# How do I make my live ubuntu on a USB stick persistant?

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb

I have just downloaded the Ubuntu .iso file and installed it on a 16gb USB I bought. While going through the installation setup I ran into the installation type (since I want to run it on a USB, while everything I do saves on it). I encountered some sort of text that showed the following things.

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 (sda2,3,4,5,6)
```

As said before, I want everything done on Ubuntu to be saved on the USB, but I just don't understand what I must do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find this is a nice guide to make a persistent install on an USB stick or drive? [How should I make my partitions for a Full Install USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280737/how-should-i-make-my-partitions-for-a-full-install-usb)

Comment: Can you restate your question.  Not sure if you want a live Ubuntu with persistence(keeps your data only) or do you want to do a full install of Ubuntu onto a USB.  Second one a bit more dependable and also updates system.

Comment: The method for making a Live install Persistent depends on how the live pendrive was created. What tool did you use to make the drive? It is difficult using a cloning system such as Etcher, Win32DiskImager, Disks or Startup Disk Creator. While Rufus, Ventoy, UNetbootin, Universal, Yumi and mkusb all have options for persistence. Of those mkusb is my preference for a Persistent install. I usually prefer a Full install though. See answer below. To make Live install persistent see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126145/can-i-convert-a-live-ubuntu-usb-to-one-with-persistent-memory/1126305#1126305

Answer (score 1):

### Full Install vs Persistent install

With a Full install of Ubuntu to USB you can run any program that you can run on an internal drive.

**Comparison between Persistent and Full install USB**

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1. You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.
2. A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.
3. You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.
4. The install to pendrive takes less time.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1. You can update and upgrade.
2. If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in these forums).
3. No ugly startup / install screen.
4. Better security, you can use full encryption
5. You can use proprietary drivers.
6. Hibernation works.
7. A persistent install is limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.
8. More efficient usage of disk space. Does not require reserved space for persistence.
9. Faster boot, **no automatic disk checking** or Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu screen.
10. You can do anything, run any program, use any driver, etc, that you can do on internal drive.

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed. If the computer has lots of RAM Ubuntu should run mainly in RAM and there will not be a bi difference between running off internal HDD and USB3 flash drive.

**Full Install Method**
Three methods for creating a Full install USB: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-st)