# Dual Boot with Windows 11 . partition size for root,home and swap?

Tags: partitioning

trying to install a dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 11. I am following a youtube guide and the guy is saying to create 3 partitions in the install part - root,home and swap . Now I have no idea what sizes these need to be. this will be for my attempt at least to try and create my own offline openstreet map tile server, this is going to be on 2tb SSD where the tile server needs at least 1.5tb. Basically where are PostgreSQL and MySQL databases located, root or home? Yeah total newbie to linux.

Comment: You can ask that guy who suggested creating those partitions. It is a matter of opinions. The recommended way is NOT to create separate `/home` and `/swap` partitions. But in some cases they can be made. You can always change it later.

Comment: I get no root file system if I try and select the sata drive where I am installing though?

Comment: You need at lease one `/` partition. Modern Ubuntu systems use a swap file, so there is no need in a swap partition in most cases, etc.

Comment: Ah ok, so the whole space under / then? Thanks.

Comment: You need only a single partition (`/`) for a *legacy* (BIOS/CSM/MBR) box, and two partitions (`/` and ESP) for a uEFI/Secure-uEFI install.  What sizes they need to be however will vary on what Ubuntu product (server? desktop? etc) and how you'll use it (will you be adding packages? how many, what size data etc)..  Most of those questions only the installer can know (*ie. read their plans for intended usage of the install*).  Swap partition is **not** required if you'll use *swapfile* (but *swapfile* mandates a slightly larger *fs* to store it etc. thus ask the person who's planned out usage)

Comment: Thanks, the person that made the video just talks about installing, no specific needs. I have uEFI so 2 partitions? root and home?. All my space needs to be for a tile server so postgresql and apache . That root or home? Basically this is wall I will be using Ubunta for - https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-18-04-osm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu on a single partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973252/installing-ubuntu-on-a-single-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info for a categorical answer. Earlier comments list some of the unknowns. (E.g. is this on BIOS or UEFI? Are you using MBR or GPT partitioning?) I can only make general comments and recommendations, such as: get some Linux experience yourself before trying to do something like this. Install the desktop OS and use it as your main OS for a few days. As for partition sizes, my general guidelines are: root (`/`) 32GB, 64GB if you will add a *lot* of additional software. Swap at least as big as RAM, and ideally 2x RAM. Then the `/home` partition can be as big as all the remaining space, leaving a reasonable amount for Windows. (E.g. making sure the Windows partition has at least 75% free space.)