# Installing Ubuntu by manual partitioning and completely removing windows 7

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I want to switch from windows 7 to Ubuntu.My disk is on mbr and I want to do manual partitioning, so while manual partitioning I have system reserved of 350mb of windows and C drive where windows is installed can I delete all partitions including that system reserved and create new partitions for Ubuntu as follows:

- `/boot` - 10gb
- `/swap` - 10gb
- `/root` - 450gb
- `/home` - 530gb

Am I right, can I create more partitions which will help improve performance?

Comment: The number of partitions has little to do with performance, and there's little benefit to having one dedicated to swap. Going with the default partition layout offered by the installer may make more sense as that's typically the least-limiting option for most people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu on a single partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973252/installing-ubuntu-on-a-single-partition)

Comment: Is system UEFI even if Windows 7? Most newer systems are UEFI, so you need an ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32 with esp,boot flags (if gparted). Suggested to be 300 to 500MB. Best not to use /boot unless server type install with LVM or RAID and may be optional then. Swap file is default so swap partition not required. But 4GB suggested if using swap partition. There is no /root, but just / and if data in separate partition(s) 30 to 50GB usually enough. Snaps now take more. VMs or server apps may go into /, so then more required, but new users should not need that.

Comment: You will not gain any performance by installing on multiple partitions - on the other hand, you'll make things more complicated and harder to maintain. By default, Ubuntu uses a single partition, and unless you're sure what you're doing (and then you wouldn't ask here), then install on a single partition.