# Trying to dual boot Windows 7 with Ubuntu. Install isn't recognizing windows partition

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

So I'm booting up Ubuntu 16.04 with a live USB then running the install, but for some reason the free partition isn't showing up. None of the HDD partitions show, only the USB partitions. Can any of you figure out why? Here's some more info.

So far I've shrunk the HDD using Windows disk management, now there's 31.25GB of unallocated space (doesn't show a filesystem only 'unallocated' & the other partitions are NTFS). I ran chkdsk before this.

The space is showing as "Basic" type and "MBR" partition style. There are 2 primary partitions on the C drive and 1 recovery partition. The D drive is a primary and now there's an unallocated partition too. They all show on the line "Disk 0". This should be what Ubuntu can pick up on to install on right?

There's no options for "Install alongside windows" or "something else", just able to select a language, check the box to update after installation, then straight onto the second "Installation type" screen where only the USB partitions show to select from.

Any way to fix this so Ubuntu can recognize the empty partition to install on?

---

Edit: Currently reinstalling the live USB. 
I found a potential solution for the "Install alongside windows" not showing problem.

```
sudo dmraid -rE
```

Supposedly this removes the dmraid metadata and the option should appear. Is this is safe to do? Wondering if it could it impact my data on the HDD?

---

My HDD uses raid so I don't think that's an option. I attempted to remove the GPT data with gdisk but no luck.

Tried ubuntu 14 instead, no luck either.

Now trying Ubuntu 17. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: If MBR have you used all 4 primary partitions? Just having more unallocated does not work as you cannot have 5 primary partitions. You have to convert one primary to extended and then can have as many logical partitions as you want. May sure partitions are basic, not proprietary dynamic. My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Yeah, well Disk 0 on Disk management contains 2 HDDs, the first HDD has 3 primary partitions and the second HDD has 1 primary partition. Then there's the unallocated space too. 

So currently 4 primary partitions (Recovery, System reserved, C:) + (Unallocated) + (DATA D:) 

All basic yup. So if I change the DATA D: partition on the second HDD to extended it should be good?

Comment: If you have RAID, what kind? If just a setting for Intel SRT, you can change to AHCI and remove RAID meta-data. But if RAID 0, you erase all data as half of data is on one drive and half on the other. One more reason for very good backups before starting. As long as unallocated is not really a partition, just space Ubuntu should install. Auto install will then work, but if you have lots of RAM, it tends to make swap too large. I prefer Something Else and create your own /, /home & swap partitions (as logicals).

Answer (score 0):

Use boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for fix your Problem.

Comment: Hmm tried it out but it didn't work properly said there's no network connection (there was). Currently reinstalling the live USB. 
I found a potential solution for the "Install alongside windows" not showing problem. 

Sudo dmraid -rE

Supposedly this removes the dmraid metadata and the option should appear. Do you know if this is safe to do? Could it impact my data on the HDD?

Comment: Of course not working if you haven't network connexion for install boot-repair.
You can download boot-repair live cd from : https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/