# installing ubuntu on a disk with 4 partition

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10.the problem is that I have already 4 partitions on the disk.when I create a free space from Windows while Ubuntu installation the free space is useless I can't use it to create a partition

Comment: You can't have more than 4 primary partitions in a MBR drive and that fact that you have such a drive means Windows 10 was installed in Legacy mode which is only recommended (and the only available mode) for old, BIOS based, hardware. Anywhere else use UEFI mode with GPT drives.

Comment: My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu