# Ubuntu 18.04 unusable space during install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm currently on a Win 10 Desktop and have a C D and E drive. Shrunk My C drive to install but on the install page, where it's supposed to show free space, it shows it as unusable. Googling it, the problem apparently only occurs if you have 4 partitions already but I only have 3. Any solutions to this that won't involve destroying one of my partitions?.

Fresh win 10 install which I'm pretty sure is installed in BIOS compatibility mode(I can boot into both UEFI and BIOS). Asus ASROCK350M mobo. Yeah it creates a tiny partition for itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkYgx.jpg

sys info says windows is booted in legacy mode

Comment: Post this in question above: `sudo parted -l` Is Windows 10 from Windows 7 upgrade or newer system with it pre-installed? What brand/model system? Windows in BIOS/MBR mode typically has a required boot partition, that in Windows you normally do not see.

Comment: Added extra details

Comment: Probably better to use UEFI, then you do not have 4 primary partition limit. and other 350 series systems have needed UEFI updates to work o rwork well. Some older Asrock have asmedia ports which cause confilcts, do not use them if you have them.

Comment: Damn, and if I want to remove one of the partitions? My E drive has 350 gigs space of nothing. Is it possible to resize D to give it all that space and get rid of E completely?

Comment: You have to convert one primary partition to an extended partition and then can have an unlimited number of logical partitions. Those can also be your extra NTFS partitions. But if using BIOS, Windows 10's auto update will turn fast start up back on. Grub will then not boot it. So you need your Windows repair disk to fix Windows and Ubuntu live installer to restore grub. With UEFI, you can just use UEFI to choose Windows to directly boot. 4 partitions info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Alright, thanks. Also is there anyway to permanently do something about fast startup getting re-enabled? I don't want to constantly repair windows and linux

Comment: Have not seen anything, you can check in Windows forums. But that is why UEFI is better for dual booting Windows 10 as then you can directly boot from UEFI boot menu to start it.