# Ubuntu installer is not recognizing any partition on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm sorry to post this as I am sure it is a duplicate of someone else's question, but I am totally new to this and do not know my way around when it comes to using file management in Ubuntu.

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. I have two hard drives, a 1 TB HDD that I use solely for disk images and file backup and a 500 GB SSD that I have Windows installed on and that I have created a new 40 GB partition on for Ubuntu.

Here is how things look from Windows Disk Management.

[image: Windows Disk Manager Screenshot]
When I go to use the Ubuntu installer from the USB I can only see my 1 TB drive and do not see any partition from my 500 GB SSD as an option.

Edit: here is what Gparted shows for the drive, it says more than 4 partitions as not allowed, is that related to my issue? 
[image: gparted info]

Comment: Can you open gparted on "try Ubuntu" and tell us which drives are visible?

Comment: OK I opened G Parted, I can see both drives as well as the partition I wish to install into, it is simply I identified as unallocated.  Do I need to format the partition to make it usable by the installer?

Comment: See this: My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your disk uses dos partitioning instead of gpt, you have a limit of 4 primary partitions (which are already present, so no more allowed).  You either need to convert your disk go gpt partitioning which allows 128+ partitions (Microsoft offers a tool which might work for you since you presently have only Microsoft filesystems), or temporarily backup/delete a primary (the 400M diag one), create an extended partitoin over all the now free space, then create logical partitions within the extended partition, restoring the 400M primary you backed up, then you can create another logical partition for Ubuntu.

---

If you think sdb3 and sdb4 are useless,  just delete them and make the 65G+ unallocated space into an extended partition.  You can then make logical partitions in the extended partition, or just let the Ubuntu installer grab the whole thing.

Comment: This system is VERY old (8 years) and has more more parts replaced than Joan Rivers did.  The OEM partition really doesn't pertain to my current build, as by now most of the hardware has changes as well as the OS (windows 7 being replaced by 10).  Could i just use the oem partition instead as I think by now it serves little to no function.

Comment: If the 450 MB partition is useless as well, you can zap both of those and have a nice 66 GB partition. Check for sure what's on it, though. Might be important.

Comment: In the end I delete the old OEM partition using gparted and move that 450 mb partition to the end of the disk to get a 66 gb partition.  I do not know what the 450 mb portion is doing but for how big it is its not hurting anything and thought I was already winning by getting 66 gb partition.   Thanks to all for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Open gparted on your USB Ubuntu (try software option). I dentify the partition. It has to be formated to Ext4. You then have to set it as root directory "/". When istalling you may have to choose this partition as "something else", that is, not overwrite everything whith Ubuntu.