# Why can't Ubuntu be installed on BIOS when UEFI is existing (Windows 7 is already installed on BIOS)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

Windows 7 is installed on the first 2 partitions (100MB & 250GB) (in BIOS Mode).

Now I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on the next partition but it doesn't find Windows 7. The installer finds the partitions. If I install it on the empty partition, after finishing I can only boot Ubuntu. If I try it with Ubuntu 16.04 I get a message saying that Windows 7 is installed in BIOS mode, but it wants to install in UEFI, and that then I won't be able to use Windows 7 any more. and so it is.

But why can't Ubuntu also be installed in BIOS mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) -- (https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix/952952#952952)

Comment: How you boot install media with new UEFI hardware, is then how it installs. Probably better to have installed Windows in UEFI mode to take advantage of newer hardware, but Windows 7 default install is BIOS only, you have to change installer around a bit on flash drive. But if Windows is BIOS on MBR drive, make sure you have not used all 4 primary partitions, and boot Ubuntu installer in BIOS mode, not UEFI mode to install in BIOS boot mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Please advise how many partitions and of which type on your disc. MBR, the original partitioning method, is limited to four primary partitions; GPT, the current method, has no limit. https://www.easyuefi.com/resource/check-mbr-or-gpt.html shows how to check, and there's more helpful info at https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/mbr-vs-gpt.html and https://www.techlila.com/mbr-vs-gpt/