# Dell Inspiron 15 3000 w/Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, 1TB Hdd, want to Install Dual Boot Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

How to Dual-Boot Windows 7 Ultimate and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Different HDD Partitions..? HDD has 3 partitions all NTFS. Windows, Drive C: 459.45GB, Free Drive D: 486.87GB, Free Drive E: 12.41GB. Like to install Ubuntu on drive D: and have dual-boot..O/S. New to Ubuntu, not real sure on how to accomplish this task, please help..?
James...

Comment: Most Windows 7 systems are BIOS with MBR and its 4 primary partition limit. If you converted from basic to dynamic partitions with Windows you have to convert back. You cannot use NTFS partitions like D:, but partition will have to be totally reformatted as ext4. Be sure to make a Windows repair flash drive or have installer with repair console. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks.! I installed it on D: drive w/format from installer, yet I had no boot. I found Boot-repair and it fixed everything..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu on D or E partition. During the installing wizard you have to install the grub as well and select the first disk (sda) not the partition (e.g sda4). At the end you can reboot and select the starting O.S from the grub menu.
Remember to add the boot/efi partition if your PC has UEFI

Comment: Thanks.! I installed it on D: drive w/format from installer, yet I had no boot. I found Boot-repair and it fixed everything..! – J. Parmenter 30 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.! I installed it on D: drive w/format from installer, yet I had no boot. I found Boot-repair and it fixed everything..! – J. Parmenter 30 secs ago   edit