# How to make use of "useless" space in HD to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, 19.04, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 along with Windows 10 but I'm having trouble when making partitions in HD. I reduced the space for Windows partition and then that space went for a "ususable" partition which I can't make any use. There was another unusable partition before, but know there are two. How can I make use of it for proceding with Ubuntu installation?

I'm attaching a picture of the screen during this step of the process.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns5xG.jpg)

Comment: What you attempted to blur out can still be read. A mod can erase history though.

Comment: You have what looks like a BIOS install of Windows with MBR partitioning. MBR has a 4 primary partition limit. You will have to convert one primary to an extended partition and then inside the extended partition can have an unlimited number of logical partitions. Be sure to have good backups, a Windows repair disk, and Ubuntu live installer. Microsoft has required Windows 10 to be installed by Mfg. in UEFI mode. Is this an upgrade from old Windows 7? http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: I just deleted the /dev/sda3 partition and then the unusable partition turned into "free space", and I installed Ubuntu there. Much thanks!