# dual boot Win 7 Pro and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have been trying for days to figure this out but can't seem to understand the jargon and instructions.  Attached is current partition make up. I have ubuntu on a USB drive and can "Try ubuntu" but at this point want to put it on the HD along with win 7 Pro.  I am novice and new to linux.  Any help is appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvj2S.png)

Comment: You have used all 4 primary partitions allowed with BIOS/MBR configuration. You need to convert one primary to an extended partition. Then inside extended you can have any number of logical partitions. Probably easiest to backup Lenovo recovery, delete it  and make enough unallocated space for Ubuntu. You can also create new partition for Lenovo backup if desired. My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will give this a try.  At one point when I tried the ubuntu install, I got a message about needing a "EFI" partition.  Will I run into that again?  How do I get around that?

Comment: You must have a newer UEFI system, but with Windows in old BIOS/MBR configuration. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it wants to install. If you do not want Windows you can convert to newer UEFI, but if dual booting you need to install Ubuntu in old BIOS boot mode. UEFI uses gpt partitioning & Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt. You current install will only boot in BIOS mode. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI