# Windows 10 dual boot Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I i just bought a new dynabook with windows 10 installed on it.
I achieved to install Ubuntu 19 alongside windows 10, but after it it's impossible to boot into ubuntu. I tried changing in the bios were ubuntu appears in the boot order, but it keeps booting into windows. I've also executed the bcdedit command in windows and still grub is not appearing. Any help would be appreciated, maybe it's already solved this problem, but i didn't find a solution yet :(

#### Edit based on additional information provided as answer:

I'm attaching here some screenshots asked above for further help.

My computer is a `Dynabook Tecra X40-F-140`.

I also notice that list partition is not detecting Ubuntu's partition. I created a 600 GB partition and a 1 GB swap space in the missing space (it is a 1TB HDD), the partitions created would be between partition 3 and partition 4.

Boot options:

[image]

Current HDD boot options:

[image]

list partition output:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ubuntu 19?   Ubuntu releases are *year.month* format except for a few specialist releases which do use *year* format (but only come out on even years).  You didn't specify your actual release, but if it was Ubuntu 19.04 I'd suggest starting again with Ubuntu 19.10 as 19.04 is in it's last days of supported life (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-January/000252.html)

Comment: can you please attach an image or something like that to the post showing the number of partitions on the disk? it would be helpful.

Comment: first press `Win + R` and run diskpart in Windows. Then type `list partition` and attach the output (or you can attach an image of the disk management window).

Comment: Guiverc, i'm using UBuntu 19.10, sorry, wasn't at home at the moment and couldn't remember the distro.

Comment: No, I tried and it didn't work. It seems that the ubuntu partition is erased, after installing i rebooted into live and in Gparted there is no ext4 partition, just unallocated space in the place.

Comment: That looks like a BIOS/MBR configuration, with a 4 primary partition limit. If you create partitions in Windows it may not use the require extended partition with an unlimited number of logical partitions. Windows often converts to a proprietary dynamic partition configuration. Are partitions all basic or dynamic in Windows? My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Yeeeeeeees! that was it, thanks a lot people! i just deleted the recovery partition and an other, maybe too straighforward. I had to reinstall windows after that and it's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note: If after installing Ubuntu, you boot directly in Windows, check in UEFI settings for changing the boot order. If you see no option to set the boot to Ubuntu, you need to fix it from within Windows. When you are in Windows desktop, hover the mouse in left corner, right click and select administrator’s command prompt. Then run the following command:

bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

This should make the Grub default and hence you can access both Ubuntu and Windows from it.

https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Comment: I've run the command and nothing happened after!

Comment: Maybe, turn off secure boot in uefi/bios settings and then try again. If it works, turn it on again.

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work