# How do I create partition using gparted or fdisk?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, crash, online-storage

I was trying to create a partition using gparted but it wasn't allowing me. I logged in through root user and when I tried to create a partition, it won't let me.

And when I tried fdisk, I was able to create a partition but that crashed my storage. Hence I wanted to ask if there's some wy I can still reload the machine. I think my OS files are still safe because I created a partition for the OS in the beginning. It's the main stuff that's lost. What should I do? Also, what things should I take care of while creating partitions so that I don't crash my storage in the future?

Please let me know.

Comment: Do you know how your partitions were before? I assume that, since you said you lost files, you tried to create a new partition while there was no unallocated space for it on your disk. To create a partition in that case you have to resize (shrink) an existing partition to create enough empty space for the new one. As for recovery, I personally don't know what you could do to recover your data. Hopefully creating a new partition with fdisk did not format it.

Comment: Everything you need to know in full details. https://medium.com/@sh.tsang/partitioning-formatting-and-mounting-a-hard-drive-in-linux-ubuntu-18-04-324b7634d1e0

Comment: I used the Ubuntu installer to create the partition in the very beginning when you install the OS. So I created ext4 as one partition for my OS (20 GB) and another remaining memory as ext4 for main storage. Can you tell me more about this unallocated memory part and how do I create that? I am installing everything now. So I'll take this precaution.

Comment: @CYREX, @gkats, is there some way I can retrieve data through root? I can still see my drives by using `fdisk`

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta First of all, I suggest using gparted only since it is easier to see what you are doing. Basically a hard drive in its initial state does not have any data or partitions. To install an OS on it, one or more partitions are created to place data in them, and by default all the space in the hard drive is allocated to those partitons. 
If you wanted to create another partition, you would need to unallocate some of their allocated space (200GB for example)  using the Move/Resize option in gparted, and then you would have 200GB free space to allocate to a new partition.

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta I urge you to be careful if you do not want to permanently lose data. I haven't had the chance to use any, but you can find several recovery tools online as well as guides on how to recover data. In any case, watch out before you do anything.

Comment: @gkats, I was using gparted to create a partition. I tried creating unallocated memory but whenever I `ran the operation`, I would get an error and the partition would not create. Which is why I shifted to `fdisk` and messed up everything. I don't know why gparted didn't create the unallocated memory partition.

Comment: Are you using the old MBR configuration (only required if you want Windows in BIOS boot mode, otherwise not) or the newer gpt partitioning, which Microsoft has required since 2012 for UEFI boot. Ubuntu will boot in BIOS or UEFI from gpt if you have correct supporting partitions. If MBR see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta Maybe we could help you more if you posted more details like the exact steps you took, what commands you ran, and what errors you encountered. You can edit the original question so everyone can see the extra information without looking in comments.

Comment: @gkats, I tried to put in all the steps I did. I did save an error file but I can't access it anymore. I sincerely apologize, but since I've lost my data, I don't have a lot of information to share. I am trying to make sure this doesn't happen again. Like when I re-install the OS and create partitions, what should I ensure so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta If you do not wish to try to recover your data, you can proceed with formatting the drive and reinstalling Ubuntu on it (only if you are sure you do not have anything that you need on the same disk, like a windows partition). I believe this guide has everything you need to do that: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu/ . To avoid the same problem in the future, my only recommendaton is do not use fdisk, but gparted. If gparted did not allow you to do something it must have been for a good reason.

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta I am going to take a guess and say it did not allow you to edit a partition because that partition was mounted. Partitions need to be unmounted (not in use) to be edited. My recommendation is to use a Ubuntu bootable usb (the same one you can use for reinstalling Ubuntu) which you can create by following the guide in my previous comment. When you choose "Try Ubuntu", you have access to gparted as well as Firefox and no partitions are mounted when doing that. I think that will allow you to move/resize and create partitions without issues.

Comment: @gkats, that was a good point you picked up about mounting. I was facing problems with that, but then, I logged in as root user, and then, I was able to unmount it. So it was definitely unmounted. While watching some videos, I saw that after I assign the amount of memory I need, I have to assign what kind of drive I want, ext4, or swap or whatever. And THEN, I should click on the `apply` button. Is that correct?

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta I believe so, yes.